# Does this non-human have any significance?

Tags: monster-musume-no-iru-nichijou

In episode 10 of the anime *monster musume no iru nichijou,* this non-human girl appears here:

[image: One]

and here:

[image: Two]

She then appears again very briefly in episode 11:

[image: Three]

No other mention is made of this character, but the presence she's had has been too great for this to be a mere coincidence. Who is it?

Comment: The anime? Which anime? Maybe most people can tell by the screencaps but you should still include the title in the body or question title somewhere, perhaps for search purposes or to get someone's attention better.

Comment: @SultanofSwing Well, I was hoping the question tags would do that job, but by all means I'll make it more explicit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The character in the pictures you've posted is **Polt**.
In [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monster_Musume_characters#Polt) Wikipedia link, she's listed under the supporting characters of the manga [**Monster Musume**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Musume).

> Polt is a kobold. She is the leader of the local gym,
>   the "Sports Club Kobold", and seems to be rather hyperactive.
>   Sport is her life (any and all sports, including fishing) and she
>   strives to provide the best possible experience for her customers. She
>   is depicted as a fur-clad humanoid with tail and ears like a dog—she
>   even wears a leather collar—but with a more flat, human-like face. She
>   usually wear shorts, T-shirt and track shoes. Polt seems to be trusted
>   to a higher degree than other liminals: she has her own business and
>   is allowed to go out on her own. When Draco and Lilith 
>   are placed on parole for being out without host family supervision,
>   Polt is placed in charge of them.

The Wikia [**link**](http://dailylifewithamonstergirl.wikia.com/wiki/Polt) for Polt gives detailed information about the character. Her appearance is described as:

> While her species is a Kobold, a Germanic sprite that can take many
>   forms, she appears as an almost human woman with a wolfen face,
>   including a muzzle instead of a nose, and a wolf's tail and ears. Her
>   body, in accordance with her occupation, is very athletic; having
>   muscular arms and legs and a trim abdomen. Her breasts are of average
>   size, in comparison to other characters more prodigious breast sizes.
>   In her debut, she wears a midriff revealing black shirt with the
>   sports club's name on it and an unzipped track coat on top; jean hot
>   pants; thigh straps and wristbands; a dog collar and athletic
>   sneakers.

[**This**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=monster+musume+polt&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI6-OJi56DyAIVAhqOCh2G5wfk&biw=1366&bih=667) is the link for the Google Image Search for Polt.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, she is a Kobold named Polt and has rights most other extra-species people don't, such as being allowed to go wherever whenever without an escort.

In the manga version, she is a frequent supporting character, owning and running an extra-species gym where the girls are trial customers, as well as Kobold Stadium which is an Olympic scale establishment. She is a complete fitness nut who is always trying to figure out how to make her gym useable by all extra-species body types and frequently "volunteering" to coach people she thinks could use more exercise... whether they asked for it or not.